# Use RxJs operator like merge but keep track of source observables in the result?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs-observables

I want to combine observables as is done with the "merge" operator but I still want to be able to know which input observable emitted, is there a way to do that?

For example:

```
private result$ = merge(this.obs1$, this.obs2$).pipe(
    scan((result, change) => index + change, 0),
    shareReplay(1)
  );
```

Here both values from obs1 and obs2 will go into the "change" variable in the scan function whenever any of the input observables emit, but if I had access to a projector function where I could mark the values from the input observables with different names I could then do different things in the following scan function depending on which input observable emitted. Other operators like CombineLatest or ForkJoin do not seem to be applicable here either as they require completion or emits from all input observables.

Comment: Can you map the source observables so they include an an `id` with the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library `@react-rxjs/utils` has [a util named `mergeWithKey`](https://react-rxjs.org/docs/api/utils/mergeWithKey) that can be used like this:

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs"
import { scan, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { mergeWithKey } from '@react-rxjs/utils'

const inc$ = new Subject()
const dec$ = new Subject()
const resetTo$ = new Subject<number>()

const counter$ = mergeWithKey({
  inc$,
  dec$,
  resetTo$,
}).pipe(
  scan((acc, current) => {
    switch (current.type) {
      case "inc$":
        return acc + 1
      case "dec$":
        return acc - 1
      case "resetTo$":
        return current.payload
      default:
        return acc
    }
  }, 0),
  startWith(0),
)
```

The implementation is pretty straight-forward:

```
import { merge, Observable, ObservableInput, from, SchedulerLike } from "rxjs"
import { map } from "rxjs/operators"

/**
 * Emits the values from all the streams of the provided object, in a result
 * which provides the key of the stream of that emission.
 *
 * @param input object of streams
 */
export const mergeWithKey: <
  O extends { [P in keyof any]: ObservableInput<any> },
  OT extends {
    [K in keyof O]: O[K] extends ObservableInput<infer V>
      ? { type: K; payload: V }
      : unknown
  }
>(
  x: O,
  concurrent?: number,
  scheduler?: SchedulerLike,
) => Observable<OT[keyof O]> = (input, ...optionalArgs) =>
  merge(
    ...(Object.entries(input)
      .map(
        ([type, stream]) =>
          from(stream).pipe(
            map((payload) => ({ type, payload } as any)),
          ) as any,
      )
      .concat(optionalArgs) as any[]),
  )
```

Is this what you needed?

Comment: Yes this is exactly how I'd like to solve it. I would've preferred if it was built in to RxJs. Thanks for providing the source code.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to keep track of which input observable emitted, then you may need to add metadata to your source observable. Without knowing the context of how `result$` is used, this is the best possible solution with the information given.

I would suggest adding an `id` property to each observable you need to keep track of. Then, you can use some strategy in your scan operator based on the ID.

Below is a simple example using an `id` for each source observable. In the `scan` operator you will see how my strategy changes based on the ID.

```
import { interval, merge, of } from "rxjs";
import { map, scan, shareReplay } from "rxjs/operators";

const obs1$ = interval(1000).pipe(map(i => ({ i, id: "obs1" })));
const obs2$ = interval(3000).pipe(map(i => ({ i, id: "obs2" })));

let index = 0;

const result$ = merge(obs1$, obs2$).pipe(
  scan((result, change) => {
    if (change.id === "obs1") {
      return index + change.i;
    }

    if (change.id === "obs2") {
      return index + change.i * 2;
    }
  }, 0),
  shareReplay(1)
);

result$.subscribe(console.log);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-as5ket